# how to call a sibling component method from the `router-outlet`?

Tags: angular, angular5

In my `router-outlet` there is no.of pages going sit. In the any of the pages, I would like to call another components method which common for all.

how to achieve that?

here is my code :

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> //home page, service page etc..
    <general-component></general-component> //how to call a method here?
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use a service?

Comment: when you want to call method , on router change?

Comment: No not in router change. I would like to show a popup with appropriate pages with unique message, so how to send it through `router-outlet` to `general-component` as a params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use service. But if you really want to use the component. You can just call the

```
Inside your template.
<router-outlet>
    <general-component #variablename></general-component>
<router-outlet>

on your router-outlet.component.ts
@viewChild('variablename') variablename : YourGeneralComponent;
this.variablename.aGeneralComponentMethod();
```

any where as long as you properly imported it on the app module
and then you can call the methods inside the GeneralComponent inside the component that where you need the General components

Comment: let me try your approach. but I am looking to call a method with params

Comment: yes sure. Its calling methods and updating values using parent component to its child component

Comment: @GeneSescon -   I done like you said. there is method, but not calling the method instead getting and error as `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'popMessage' of undefined` - what is the reason?